# Expression error in winform radGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, radgridview

I have a radGridView bound to a SQL table. One of the column shall contain a calculated result.

```
this.radGridView1.Columns[4].Expression = "Due - Paid";
```

All 3 fields involved are nvarchar type. I get this error and I do not understand how to fix it:
[image]

Any hint on what could be possibly wrong?

Comment: @GrantWinney they are both defined as nvarchar(50) in the table.

Comment: @GrantWinney, thanks for the hint. I will try to change them to int or decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to replicate this. It's due to the column types you're trying to subtract.

I created a `RadGridView` and populated it using this code, which compiles fine but displays the exact error you received when it tries to display the grid at runtime.

```
radGridView1.Columns.Add(new GridViewTextBoxColumn("age"));
radGridView1.Columns.Add(new GridViewTextBoxColumn("iq"));
radGridView1.Columns.Add(new GridViewDecimalColumn("total"));

radGridView1.Rows.Add("5", "5");

radGridView1.Columns["total"].Expression = "age - iq";
```

Changed the column types accordingly and it worked fine:

```
radGridView1.Columns.Add(new GridViewDecimalColumn("age"));
radGridView1.Columns.Add(new GridViewDecimalColumn("iq"));
```

You just need to make sure the column data are numbers, not strings.

Comment: Just to share it for the future. To make it working I had to change also the data type in the DB table to int and update the dataset. Your pointed me to the right direction.